# Default route url in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how I can display the full route url in browser's address bar for default route?
In my case I have 2 possible default route url, http://www.test.com/it/index and http://www.test.com/en/index, they differ onlky for language code after domain name.
In my website I use this value to display different languages of the content, every page works correctly, but the home page (that is the dafault route) will not display the complete url in the address bar.
All I need is to display /it/index in the address bar simply typing www.test.com.
For now I will do a redirect but it isn't a good solution for seo purpose due to double request.

Comment: Do you want to have /it/index in URLs you generate in the website?

Comment: There is not way browser would know to add /it/index to www.test.com without redirect.

Comment: How did you retrieve culture ? When the user is logged and personal parameters or by browser culture ?

Comment: There's no way to do this without a redirect. If you do a permanent redirect, search engines and such will pick up on this and remove the only-domain version from results. However, either way, it has no effect on SEO. Google and other search engines do not penalize your site for doing redirects. On the contrary, they encourage them, as it helps them exclude duplicate content, and update URLs for resources that have changed.

Comment: thanks Chris, I will pick up and go on without worrying about this.

Comment: @User.Anonymous I use a parameter in the route (default value "en") and for every controller I want to get localized I used an attribute that read the lang parameter and set the thread culture (and other parts of my localization engine)